# jQuery object disabled event listener, how to detect when a html attribute changes

Tags: jquery, events, attributes, listener

I need to make an event listener for a `select` tag. It should be triggered any time the element becomes `disabled` or `enabled`.

Is this even possible?

P.S.: `onchange` does not detect disabling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using this jquery `.watch` plugin.

http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/

The plugin detects for css changes, but i edited it in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4zwz/) to work for attributes.

[Check out this JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/L4zwz/)

Comment: Is it possible to turn it off/on according to my needs?

Comment: I don't remember (Sorry!), this was from a few years ago now, The github repo can be found here: https://github.com/darcyclarke/Watch.js - You should be able to look over the source code and see if there is a function or property to toggle it.

Answer (score 12):

**JQuery 1.6+**

You can change jQuery prophooks:

```
jQuery.propHooks.disabled = {
  set: function (el, value) {
    if (el.disabled !== value) {
      el.disabled = value;
      value && $(el).trigger('disabledSet');
      !value && $(el).trigger('enabledSet');
    }
  }
};
```

This will trigger "disabledSet" if element is disabled via:

```
$(element).prop('disabled', true);
```

and will trigger "enabledSet" if element is enabled via:

```
$(element).prop('disabled', false);
```

Then you can just listen to your event like this:

```
$(element).on('disabledSet', myDisabledHandler);
```