# Listening for an element disable event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to listen for the `disabled` DOM property change?

Something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#myElem").prop('disabled', true);
}, 1500);

$("#myElem").on('disabled', function(e){
    alert('my custom code');
});
```

Here's also a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fbtpdv9f/)

**Edit:** If possible, I'd like a generic solution to this. For example, in my application, I'm using an MVVM framework (Knockout), that handles internally the property change:

```
<button data-bind="disable: time > 3">
</button>
```

I'm declaring the disabling logic, but I'm not disabling it manually. What I want to do manually, is hook to that event, so I can do my custom logic.

I've seen an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460242/jquery-object-disabled-event-listener-how-to-detect-when-a-html-attribute-chang) here on SO:

```
jQuery.propHooks.disabled = {
  set: function (el, value) {
    if (el.disabled !== value) {
      el.disabled = value;
      value && $(el).trigger('disabledSet');
      !value && $(el).trigger('enabledSet');
    }
  }
};
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this:

```js
// Set up a new observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // Check the modified attributeName is "disabled"
        if(mutation.attributeName === "disabled") {
            alert("disabled changed");
        }
    });    
});
// Configure to only listen to attribute changes
var config = { attributes: true };
// Start observing myElem
observer.observe(myElem, config);

// Testing the observer gets triggered
setTimeout(function() {
    myElem.disabled = true;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<input id="myElem">
```

Though it should be noted that [modern browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) is very good, IE<=10 is not supported. You *might* be able to get the older [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events#Cross-browser_support) to work in IE9/10, but they're not supported very well. Failing that, `setInterval` can be used to "watch" the element but that should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: NB: you may need to be careful if your `button` is inside a `fieldset` which can _also_ be disabled (you'd also need to observe that element)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a interval to check if its disabled

```js
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#third").prop('disabled', true);
  }, 1500);
var test=window.setInterval(function(){
    var d=$('#third').attr('disabled');
    if(d=='disabled'){
        alert('my custom code');
        clearInterval(test);
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">first</button>
<button type="button">second</button>
<button type="button" autofocus id="third">third</button>
```